# Unable to format text in textarea html css?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have this small problem. I have a textarea and a user can enter text in a specific format but when the text is saved in the database and retrieved back the spaces or the formatting that has been done by the user for entering the text is lost. How do i maintain the formatting that the user entered in the textarea. I am using django python.

```
<label  style="color: lightblue; font-size: 20px;">Query Diagnosis</label>
  <div id ="qdiagnosis" style=" width: 80%;word-wrap:break-word;font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">
  </div>
<div class="mdl-grid full-width">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
        <textarea onkeyup="$('#query_diagnosis').val($('#query_diagnosis_').val())" class="mdl-textfield__input bordered" type="text" rows="8" id="query_diagnosis_" name="query_diagnosis_"></textarea>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="notes_">Query Diagnosis</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Before saving]
[image: After saving]

Comment: Your image links seems to be not working

Comment: Please host your images with some other provider, this one won't let me look at them without adblocker or paying. Also your code needs some formatting.

Comment: Did you tried `content.replace('\n', '<br>')` ? [as mentioned in one answer]

Answer (score 1):

This is just because HTML ignores whitespace, including newlines. You can use the [`|linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) template filter to transform your newlines into HTML `br` tags.

Comment: But if that were true wouldn't their output have literal '\n' characters in?

Comment: No. HTML *ignores* newlines.